# nuxt code splitting doesn't work properly

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm just starting with nuxtjs, i have 2 pages

-index
-map

map page has one component, which is client only
and the default layout has links to the 2 pages, just the basic setup
the production build generates code split for the vendor per page but both files loads at the first page, i can't find what am i missing.

map page

```
  <div class="container">
    <client-only>
      <Map />
    </client-only>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Map from '~/components/Map.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Map
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

index page

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="h-1">test hello page index</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  components: {

  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

default layout

```
<template>
  <div>
    <nuxt-link to="/">home</nuxt-link>
    <nuxt-link to="/map">map</nuxt-link>
    <nuxt />
  </div>
</template>

<style>
</style>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `nuxt-link` [prefetches](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router#prefetchlinks) the page it is linked to when it appears inside the viewport.

It's for performance reason and should not impact the initial loading of the page, since the prefetching is done [during idle time](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/7b3155347cb81a96b9f5080340615161a024312f/packages/vue-app/template/components/nuxt-link.client.js#L47).

If you would like to verify that what you are seeing is because of the prefetching, you can disable prefetching on per link basis by adding a `no-prefetch` attribute to `nuxt-link` or configuring router in `nuxt.config.js`

```
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  router: {
    prefetchLinks: false
  }
}
```

This is done only if user is on good network connection and not using save data mode. And, since this is done in browser's idle time, I'd suggest, leave it like this. Should not hurt.